# utrace patch for linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, systemtap

I am currently working on a firewall with linux kernel. I want to extract the user space application information by using the utrace feature. I am able to probe event of the kernel space but not of the user space. It is saying that CONFIG_UTRACE not set.

I am also using the kernel 2.6.35 and Ubuntu 10.10. As I went through one of the thread, I came to know that I have to patch the kernel 2.6.35 with the utrace. But I am not able to find the patch.

I would be highly thankful to you if you can give me the link of the patch and explain me how to patch it into the current kernel.
And explain me the further steps, if any, needed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is probably all information you need: http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/utrace

Patch for your kernel version: http://userweb.kernel.org/~frob/utrace/2.6.35/utrace.patch

Have fun!

Comment: @IHeartAndroid I can't help you with this, sorry.